# Permutations with same order are conjugate?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I know that two permutations are conjugate if they have the same cycle structure. For example $\sigma_{1} = (1,2,3)(4,5,6)(8,9,12)$ and $\sigma_{2}=(4,5,1)(2,3,8)(12,9,7)$ are adjoin.

Is it true to say that two permutations are conjugate if they have the same order? the order of $\sigma_{1}$ and $\sigma_2$ is $3$ so it fits. But is it true for all permutations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In $S_4$, $(1\ \ 2)$ and $(1\ \ 2)(3\ \ 4)$ both have order $2$, but they are not conjugate.

Comment: Thank you! So what would be the fastest way to calculate $\sigma^k$?

Comment: If you have $\sigma$ expressed as the product of disjoint cycles, then $\sigma^k$ is the product of the $k^{\text{th}}$ power of those cycles.

Comment: That I understand. for example I want to calculate $\alpha^6$ where $\alpha=(1,5,7)(2,4,6,10)(3,8,9)$ so we get $(1,5,7)^6(2,4,6,10)^6(3,8,9)^6$. But what now? should I calculate $\sigma^2,\sigma^3,\sigma^4,\sigma^5,\sigma^6$ for each one of the cycles? what if I have a bigger order like $100$?

Comment: The cycles $(1\ \ 5\ \ 7)$ and $(3\ \ 8\ \ 9)$ have both order $3$ and therefore their $6^{\text{th}}$ powers are the identity. And $(2\ \ 4\ \ 6\ \ 10)$ has order $4$ and therefore its $6^{\text{th}}$ power is equal to its square. Therefore, $\alpha^6=(2\ \ 6)(4\ \ 10)$.

Comment: consider $m=o(\sigma)$. so if $gcd(s,m)\neq 1$ then $\sigma^s=id$?

Comment: No. If $\gcd(s,m)\neq1$, then $\sigma^s\neq\operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Wait, why? $o((1,5,7))=3$ and $gcd(6,3)\neq 1$  so $(1,5,7)^6=id$ no?

Comment: @abuka123 Of course! My mistake. But it is nevertheless false. Take $\sigma=(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)$. Them $m=4$. Now, take $s=2$. Then $\gcd(s,m)\neq1$, but $\sigma^2=(1\ \ 3)(2\ \ 4)\neq\operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out (opened a second thread to ask about the condition). Thank you, again!